# Sum all values between indicators. In VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have 3 columns. Two of which are identifiers and the other is a number.
I start off with the data looking like this;

```
ID1     ID2     Number
2.41    One     1408
2.46    One     41
2.51    One     22
2.69    One     1284
1.005   Two     820
1.005   Two     2267
1.005   Two     962
1.005   Two     249
1.706   Two     1096
1.706   Two     1061
1.706   Two     1326
1.706   Two     266
1.706   Two     854
1.706   Three   412
1.12    Three   548
1.12    Three   1331
1.12    Three   3094
1.12    Three   4999
1.12    Three   5739
1       Three   69
1       Three   7212
1       Three   4999
```

And I want to sum the Number when both IDs are the same and in consecutive rows i.e. end up with;

```
ID1     ID2     Number
2.41    One     1408
2.46    One     41
2.51    One     22
2.69    One     1284
1.005   Two     4298
1.706   Two     4603
1.706   Three   412
1.12    Three   16123
1       Three   12280
```

I need to do this via a VBA macro, as this will be a repeated process and thus any user must be able to get the data looking like this from a push of a button.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please insert as pictures rather than misaligned text

Comment: **1)** You can probably do this without VBA and use formulas **2)** SO is not a code for me site. If you don't post what you have tried and where it's failing, you'll get little help.

Comment: Research SUMIFs

Comment: Don't think you need VBA, a simple formula or pivot table should get you what you need.

Comment: What happens when non consecutive IDs match in rows across both columns?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the column next to Number and copy it to the bottom of your data.

> =SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=A2),--(B:B=B2),C:C)

This will only sum when the value in column A and the value in column B match.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a 3rd ID column, "=A1&A2". This will create a unique ID that you can group together.

There is a subtotal feature under the Data tab, under "outline", you can specify to sum "number" after each change in ID3. This will provide totals that you are looking for. This will produce "mini columns" to the left of the rows, click on the 1,2,3 to show and hide detail. Hope this helps, Please leave a comment if you do this and have any questions :)